# Plot datetime64 with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to do a simple time series plot of the weekly index values of the muni swap index over time. I am unable to get the dates in the chart to show as dates.

```
%pylab inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import datetime as dt

ind = pd.read_csv("muni-swap-historical-data.csv")

ind.head(10)
```

```
Date      IndexValue
7/5/1989  6.06   
7/12/1989 5.77  
7/19/1989 5.93  
7/26/1989 6.09  
8/2/1989  5.91  
8/9/1989  5.94  
8/16/1989 6.17  
8/23/1989 6.19  
8/30/1989 6.15  
9/6/1989  6.03
```

```
ind_clean = ind.copy()
ind_clean['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ind_clean['Date'])
ind_clean['Date'] = ind_clean['Date'].astype(dt.datetime)

ind_clean['Date'].head(10)
```

```
0   1989-07-05 00:00:00  
1   1989-07-12 00:00:00  
2   1989-07-19 00:00:00  
3   1989-07-26 00:00:00  
4   1989-08-02 00:00:00  
5   1989-08-09 00:00:00  
6   1989-08-16 00:00:00  
7   1989-08-23 00:00:00  
8   1989-08-30 00:00:00  
9   1989-09-06 00:00:00
```

```
ind_clean.plot(title='KBW BKX Index Timeseries').legend(loc=6,
                                                        bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

Plot output:

[image: Plot output]

***EDIT: An issue was being caused by the naming of the 'IndexValue' column. Changing this to 'Value' in the csv file fixed the problem. Working code is below.

```
%pylab inline

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
#import datetime as dt

ind = pd.read_csv("muni-swap-historical-data.csv")

ind['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ind['Date'])
#unnecessary ind['Date'] = ind_clean['Date'].astype(dt.datetime)

ind.plot(x='Date', y='Value', title='SIFMA Muni Swap Index Timeseries').legend(loc=6, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

[image: Graph Output]

Comment: Where does `bkx_clean` come from?

Comment: That is my fault I had confused a few indexes I was looking at and mixed this up with the KBX BKX index. I have corrected this in the notes above to reflect how my code is structured in Jupyter Notebook. The title of the chart is still misleading...

Comment: `ind_clean.plot(x='Date', y='IndexValue', ...)`?

Comment: I get a key error using above. KeyError: 'IndexValue'

Comment: I think it is an issue with using a reserved word? I changed 'IndexValue' to 'Value' and it worked. Very frustrating. Can anyone verify why this would be an issue. Thanks ali_m

Comment: What's the purpose of `ind_clean['Date'].astype(dt.datetime)`? You're already casting that column to datetime64 on the previous line.

Comment: @ali_m you are correct. I was unsure of why this would not work so I was trying variations. Looks like it had something to do with the name of the column/list. Thanks again.